# keystore is lost,while app is on Beta channel

Tags: android

I found several questions about this topic,but none of them specified the best workaround.So I accidentaly deleted my keystore and can't recover it.My app is live on play market Beta channel,it also has an IOS version.So what would we the best solution?deactivate the app that is on beta channel and place a new one?In that case must I change app package name or not?Please note that app has facebook login and firebase live database integrated.
Any help is appreciated,thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even for a beta version :

- Android does not allow the signature to change.
- Google Play Store does not allow the package name to change.

These are [things that can not change](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2011/06/things-that-cannot-change.html)

So if you chose to manage your own key (as opposed to [Google Play App Signing](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html#google-play-app-signing)) your only option is to create a new application, and remove the old one (or maybe update the description to inform the current users)

The 'new' application can access the existing Firebase database, if you add it to the Firebase project (this creates a new `google-service.json`)

I don't know how Facebook login works.

Comment: So the new google-service.json should be updated on IOS also right?

Comment: I don't know how iOS pusblishing works but the iOS application is a different application, with a different api-key, linked to the same Firebase project. You don't need to touch it if you only replace the Android application

Answer (score 0):

You can contact Google Play Console Support and they will be able to reset the keystore for you to a new keystore and then you will be able to publish future updates.

In the play console click the help button at the top > Scroll down to heed more help and click "Contact Us" > Type in you need help with a Keystore Reset > Click "next step" > Click "Upload key reset request" > Click "Contact Google Play Developer Support" > Then choose a contact method to contact them to reset it for you.